# Failed to tar big file with pipe and xargs

Tags: pipe, tar, xargs

I tried to tar mysql backup files as below:

```
find /data/mysqldata \( ! -name "*mysql-bin*" -a ! -name "*.log" \) |
    xargs tar -zcf /data/backup.tgz
```

Actually, I executed this command with Popen and waited to read the output through select-poll method, however, I found that sometimes the backup file suddenly became very small after it was already very large, just like that the tar procedure was restarted. This case usually happened when the target file was extremely large and I was quite confused about that.

Comment: What do you want this to do? `tar -zcf /data/mysqldata` would create an archive called `/data/mysqldata`...

Comment: That would find all files and directories (and other things) and (potentially) overwrite the `tar` archive multiple times with each of these. Tell us instead what it is you'd like to do.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake for the command just now, I have already fixed it.

Comment: I just want to tar some files under /data/mysqldata into an archive automatically.

Comment: like `tar -czf /data/backup.tgz /data/mysqdata` but without the `mysql-bin.nnnnnn` files?

Comment: yes, now the problem is when I do this through a daemon script, the target file would become larger and larger and then suddenly become very small.

Comment: May I suggest using cpio instead of tar? Cpio and find work nicely together.

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU `tar`:

```
tar -cz -f /data/backup.tgz --exclude '*.log' --exclude 'mysql-bin.*' /data/mysqldata
```

---

The issue that you ran into was that `xargs` executed `tar` multiple (at least two) times. The second time `tar` was run, the backup file would "shrink" (get overwritten).

This is what `xargs` does.  It executes a utility with as many arguments as possible, and when it get more arguments (filenames in your case), it chops the list off and continues with the list in another invocation of the utility.

The issue *occured* because you sent every single directory and filename to `xargs`, generating a very long list.

Comment: I was just testing this method, I was confused mainly because there were some factors that affect my estimation, such as pipe, file size, and tar command itself.

Comment: that is to say, when the list is very long, xargs will restart the utility from some intermediate item?

Comment: @perse Correct.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the list of files to the archiving command directly instead of `xargs` which could (and does in some of your case) split the list into several archiver invocations.

Here using the standard `pax` command though with `-print0`/`-0` non-standard extensions supported by some for added reliability:

```
find /data/mysqldata ! -name "*mysql-bin*" ! -name "*.log" -print0 |
  pax -0wd | gzip > file.tar.gz
```

(also note the `-d` without which all files would be included anyway as archiving `/data/mysqldata` (which matches neither exclusion pattern) would mean archiving everything like in your `tar` approach).

Beside `pax`, many `tar` implementations support getting the file list from stdin, but usually with different interface between implementations.